# What is the most efficent way generate the following has_many through query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

I have following models:

**Account**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, through: :members
end
```

**Member**

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts, through: :members
end
```

**Query:**
Given a `User.id`, find the account. currently I do this:

```
> u = User.take
User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
> id = Member.where(user_id: u.id).pluck(:account_id)
(0.8ms)  SELECT "members"."account_id" FROM "members" WHERE "members"."user_id" = 1
> a = Account.find(id)
Account Load (8.9ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

Wondering if there is a better or faster way to find Account, given a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the details of your models, but based on the error, it looks like you need the `members` association in your `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :accounts, through: :members
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do

```
u = User.take
a = u.accounts.find(id)
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :members in model User`